# American put option and rising interest rate

Tags: options, put

Will a rise in interest rate always result in a lower price of an American put option?

Answer (score 1):

Generally no. Check page 21 of the following document:

http://www.frankfurt-school.de/clicnetclm/fileDownload.do?goid=000000053103AB4